# Change display size of one image in a Gallery block

Tags: gallery

I'm new to Wordpress.  I've created a simple blog site, pretty much just out of the box, latest 6.2.2 version.

When I create a post, it uses the block editor.  When I create a Gallery block, and add images, sometimes there's a single image on the last row all by itself, and it gets blown up to full width and looks too big compared to the other rows of images.

[image]

I'd like to know a way to change the size of this one image to be like the size of the other 3 images in the first row of the gallery, only landscape. It would be nice if it was centered too.  And no hardoding a smaller image size in pixels, so that the gallery can still look good on desktop as well as mobile.

I've tried selecting the one image in the gallery, and changing image size from Large to Thumbnail, however it doesn't change the display size.  It only makes the image blurry, but it still remains huge.

[image]

Thanks in advance!